# input tag inside bootstrap dropdown does not work properly in Safari Browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, safari, jquery-file-upload

I've been working on getting jQueryFileUpload working however I'm getting a weird issue that only occurs on Safari, particularly I'm on (5.1.7 7534.57.2).

I have an input element that I initialize with the plugin [jQueryFileUpload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to allow for file uploading. This plugin then listens for events such as selecting a file, in this simple example you should see a progress bar as soon as you select the file.

[image]
Below is my configuration for styling the input tag.

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <span>Select files...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
```

When this block of code is within a bootstrap drop down the issue on safari occurs. It still lets you click and select a file but once you select that file, nothing else happens (so you won't see the progress bar appear), no errors are triggered either it just seemed it doesn't bubble up to where it should.

I've created a repo with the project at https://github.com/newtonianb/jfl_safari and I would much appreciate any help on understanding what is going on.

The **master** branch has the input in the drop down so that it does not work on safari.
The **working** branch simply has the same input tag in the body instead and here it works on safari.

Why is this issue happening in the drop down only on safari and how can I fix this? 
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update some Bootstrap CSS to make it work.

Add the following CSS into some of your CSS files to override Bootstrap CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.open .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This CSS fix is working for me on Safari 5.1.7